# Define custom generic setter for JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript

I wonder if it's possible to define a custom `setter()` function for a javascript `class`.
I know this is possible thanks to a `Proxy`:

```
class Person {
  name;
  surname;

  constructor({name, surname}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }
}

const customSetter = {
  set: function(obj: any, prop: any, value: any) {
    obj[prop] = value;

    // Performing custom operations.

    return true;
  }
}

const ProxiedClass = <T, V>(obj: T, classGenerator: { new(obj: T): V}) : any => new Proxy(new classGenerator(obj), customSetter);

var foo = ProxiedClass({name: 'pippo', surname: 'pluto'}, Person);

console.log(foo); // → Object { name: "pippo", surname: "pluto" }
```

Though, there are few things that I don't like about this solution:

1. Since I would have lots of classes, I would like to have a generic Proxy like the one I implemented, but then the most important keyword, the one that define which type we will have, it's just an argument (`Person` is passed as argument).
2. Assume I even create a single `Proxy` for each class (like `ProxiedPerson`).. Another thing I don't like is that I cannot call it with `new`: if another developers read the line, he doesn't read right away the fact  that I'm creating a new instance because we are missing the `new` keyword.
3. Once the object is shown in console, we also lose the name of the class: you see that it's shown `Object` instead of `Person`.

I know these are not big issues, but i'm trying to write "user-friendly" code, and to me this solution it seems not user-friendly at all.

I also know it's possible to define a setter and getter function for each property, but I'd like to avoid that.

---

EDIT: After @Bergi comments, I tried to do something like he suggests.

Some more info on the big picture I'm trying to achieve: I want to implement some sort of validation, like we were in C#: I have classes with attributes, and I managed to retrieve the attributes/functions when a class property change.
Though, I need to run the functions in the `setter()` method, that's why I need to intercept the `setter()`.

So, I thought of recreating the `ValidatingObject` `class`: if a `class` extends `ValidatingObject`, then the `setter()` properties method are intercept are handled.
I managed to do something:

```
class ValidatingObject {
  public hasValidationError : boolean;
  public validationErorrs : any;

  constructor() {
    this.hasValidationError = false;
    this.validationErorrs = {};

    let properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);

    properties.forEach(p => {
      Object.defineProperty(this, "_" + p, {value: this[p], writable: true});
      Object.defineProperty(this, p,
        {
          get: function() { return this["_" + p]},                    
          set: (v: any) => { this["_" + p] =  v; console.log("Perfom custom OP"); } 
        }
      );
    });
  }
}

class Person extends ValidatingObject {
  public name;
  public surname;

  constructor({name, surname}) {
    super();

    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }
}

var foo = new Person({name: 'pippo', surname: 'pluto'});
foo.hasValidationError = true; // → 'Perform custom OP' shown in console.
foo.name = "paperino"; // → Nothing shown in console.
```

But now, I've another problem. In the `constructor` of `ValidatingObject`, when I run `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)`, I got only the `ValidatingObject` properties, and not the ones in `Person`, thus I haven't intercepted the `setter()` method I wanted the most.

So, another question now could be: is there any way I can get `Person` properties from `ValidatingObject`?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create setters only for a defined set of properties? Then do not use proxies.

Comment: No, I do want to create a setter for all the properties of the class. I know it's possible with `Proxy`, but I was wonder if it's possible without (the reasons are above)

Comment: That's what I said, "all the properties of a class" are a known set. You should use setters and getters for them - but without spelling them out. Make a helper function that creates them automatically.

Comment: Oh, well you're right. Sorry, I intended a sub-set :S
Yeah, what you suggest it could work.. But i've some doubt how could I create them automatically.
EDIT: More infos on my doubts: ok, in the same file with the classes, I create a function that takes each class and use `defineProperties`, I guess. And then, I would just call the function right away in the file.
But, would this work in a react app? wouldn't be computationally expansive?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you'd use `Object.defineProperty`, and invoke the helper function on the class, possibly passing in the names of the properties. Or even have a look at decorators if you're fine with experimental syntax. Yes, this should work just fine in a react app. And yes, getters/setters are more computationally expensive, but still far less than proxies.